# Passing string from c# to c++ dll

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I am trying to pass a string from C# to C++ dll. The string that I recieve in the dll is some wierd characters. Here is my code.

In C++ dll:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "ProcessCheckerDll.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include "Shlwapi.h"
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>


namespace ProcessCheck
{
string GetRunningProcessFromHierarchy(char* argStrRoot)
{ 
    char ch;
    printf("Reached here 1.");
    scanf_s("%c",&ch);

    std::string strRoot(argStrRoot,strlen(argStrRoot));
    printf_s("strRoot = %s",strRoot);
    std::ifstream input("d:\\filelist.txt");
    std::string line;

    printf("Reached here 2.");
    scanf_s("%c",&ch);

    //printf("cdsroot=%ls",strRoot);

    std::transform(strRoot.begin(), strRoot.end(), strRoot.begin(), ::tolower);
    std::vector<std::string> collection;
    string result="";


    printf("Reached here 3.");
    scanf_s("%c",&ch);

    HANDLE hProcessSnap=nullptr;
    HANDLE hProcess;
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
    DWORD dwPriorityClass;


    while( std::getline( input, line ) )
    {
        //Get the file name from path
        std::wstring strPathFromTextFile = std::wstring(line.begin(), line.end());
        LPCWSTR absolutePathToFile = strPathFromTextFile.c_str();
        LPCWSTR onlyFileName = PathFindFileName(absolutePathToFile); 

        // Take a snapshot of all processes in the system.
        hProcessSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
        if(hProcessSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            printf("Failed to get the snapshot of running processes");
            return result;
        }

        pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

        // Retrieve information about the first process and exit if unsuccessful
        if(!Process32First(hProcessSnap, &pe32))
        {
            printf("Failed to get the first process from the list");
            CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);     // clean the snapshot object
            return result;
        }

        // Now walk the snapshot of processes, and display information about each process in turn
        do
        {
            LPCWSTR processFileName = pe32.szExeFile;

            if(lstrcmpi(onlyFileName,processFileName)==0)
            {
                //If file name is same, check if path starts with cdsroot
                HANDLE processHandle = NULL;
                TCHAR filePath[MAX_PATH];

                processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pe32.th32ProcessID);


                if (processHandle != NULL)
                {
                    if (GetModuleFileNameEx(processHandle, NULL, filePath, MAX_PATH) == 0)
                    {
                        printf("\nFailed to get module filename.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        std::wstring w_str(filePath);
                        std::string absolutePath(w_str.begin(), w_str.end());
                        std::transform(absolutePath.begin(), absolutePath.end(), absolutePath.begin(), ::tolower);

                        printf_s("Absolute path = %s", absolutePath);
                        printf_s("Matching with cdsroot = %s",strRoot);
                        if(absolutePath.find(strRoot)==0)
                        {
                            std::wstring processName(processFileName);
                            std::string strProcess(processName.begin(),processName.end());
                            printf_s("\nROOT match for Process name = %s",strProcess);

                            if (std::find(collection.begin(), collection.end(), strProcess) == collection.end())
                            {
                                collection.push_back(strProcess);
                                printf_s("\nAdding to collection Process name = %s",strProcess);
                                result = result + strProcess + ";";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    CloseHandle(processHandle);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("\nFailed to open process.");
                }
            }
        }
        while(Process32Next(hProcessSnap, &pe32));
    }

    CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);
    printf("Returning result %s", result);
    scanf_s("%c",&ch);
    return result;
}
}
```

The header file contains:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

namespace ProcessCheck
{
extern "C" { __declspec(dllexport) string GetRunningProcessFromHierarchy(char* argStrRoot); }
}
```

And the code in C# is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ProcCheckTest
{
class Program
{

    [DllImport("C:\\Users\\himanshu\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\ProcessCheck\\Release\\ProcessCheckerDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern string GetRunningProcessFromHierarchy([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string strRoot);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string strRoot = "C:\\test\\today_16.6";
        string returnValue = GetRunningProcessFromHierarchy(strRoot);
    }
}
}
```

The string that I am passing is "C:\test\today_16.6" but when I print the same in the dll code, it prints weird characters.
What is wrong here?

Comment: Please, do not post your entire code when the problem shows itself in tiny snippet - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: It could be the culture settings but my guess would be that you are using the wrong variable type which is offsetting the bytes of the string. As to which you need I can't remember at the minute

Comment: Make sure, that you're not confusing unicode with ANSI. Set appropriate attribute parameter for DllImport.

Comment: This code cannot work properly when called from C++ either.  Always unit-test native code before you try to pinvoke it.  And make sure there's a good reason to *need* native code, there is nothing in that function that cannot be done in C# with the StreamReader and Process classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue appears to be here:

```
printf_s("strRoot = %s",strRoot);
```

The problem is that `strRoot` is of type `std::string` but the format string needs a `char*`. Change this to:

```
printf_s("strRoot = %s",strRoot.c_str());
```

Or use `argStrRoot` directly.

Your other problem is the return value of the function. Currently you return `std::string`. You can't marshal that with p/invoke. You'll need to return `char*`. What's more, as it stands, the marshaller will call `CoTaskMemFree` on the pointer it receives as the return value. So you'd need to allocate the `char*` that you return with `CoTaskMemAlloc`.